# Bash script for decrypting all files inside folder

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl

I am using cygwin and I want help with creating a bash script to decrypt all files inside folder. now for decryption part script should check segment number in filename (file names are like 1_segment, 2_segment etc) and genrate hexadecimal value of that file. now decryption goes like below.

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in 121_segment121_9_av.ts -out  test.ts -d -K 443CEB41F639B41CE29D1507647A3737 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000079
```

K is key value which is same for every file
iv is hexadecimal value of segment no which changes for each file.

Pls help I am really stuck here.

Regards
Adi

Comment: `for` loops work in cygwin? I don't understand the "-iv" part, is it derived from filename somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in path/to/directory/**; do
    segmentNo=$(echo "${i##*/}" | grep -o "^[0-9]*")
    if [[ ! -f $i ]]; then
        continue
    elif [ "$segmentNo" == "" ]; then
        echo "File $i does not start with a segment no"
        continue
    fi
    hexVal=$(functionThatGeneratesHexFromInput "$segmentNo")
    openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in "$i" -out  test.ts -d -K 443CEB41F639B41CE29D1507647A3737 -iv $hexVal
done
```

Comment: And replace `functionThatGeneratesHexFromInput` with whatever you use to generate the hex values from the segment number, passing `"$segmentNo"` to that function. And replace `path/to/directory` with the location of these files

Comment: `for i in $(find ...)` is a broken design: it fails if there are filenames containing spaces or glob characters or other funny symbols. Don't use this. Even better: go and complain to the guy who showed you this _trick_.

Comment: Interesting, tell me more. And what should one use as an alternative?

Comment: Sane alternative 1: what you just did! use globs instead of `find` altogether (but hidden files will not be found unless you `shopt -s dotglob`). In your edit, you should explicitly check that `i` is a file with `[[ -f $i ]]` (your previous `find` command had `-type f`). By the way, in this case, you should also use `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: Sane alternative `2`: use `find` with its `-exec` flag. This is, most of the times, the best thing to do if you want to stick with `find`, and if it's not too difficult to pack everything into the `-exec` command.

Comment: Sane alternative `3`: with GNU `find` and `find` that support `-print0`: loop through the output of `find` (that you'll use with the `-print0` flag) as so: `while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ....; done < <(find .... -print0)`.

Comment: By the way: instead of looping through all files and then checking that filename starts with a number, why don't you directly loop through all files, the name of which starts with a number? like so: `shopt -s nullglob globstar extglob; for i in path/to/directory/**/+([[:digit:]])*; do` and then you can get the `segmentNo` either with a regex: `[[ $i =~ /([[:digit:]]+)[^/]*$ ]]; segmentNo=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` or with a pattern expansion: `segmentNo=${i##*/} segmentNo=${segmentNo%%[^[:digit:]]*}`. No ugly `echo | grep` needed.

Comment: OK, I've added the file condition, which is important. Thanks for letting me know the pitfalls of `for i in $(find ...)`. Matching dotfiles shouldn't be needed here since the OP said files are like 1_segment, 2_segment etc.

Comment: About dotfile: it's just a general difference about using `find` and globs... so that you keep it in mind in general `;)`.